Error: Cannot find module 'metro-cache' when I try to run expo start --dev-client
I'm getting this error when I try to run expo start --dev-client
Error: Cannot find module 'metro-cache'
Require stack:
    - /usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo/node_modules/@expo/metro-config/build/ExpoMetroConfig.js
    - /usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo/node_modules/@expo/cli/build/src/start/server/serverLogLikeMetro.js
    - /usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo/node_modules/@expo/cli/build/src/start/server/getStaticRenderFunctions.js
    - /usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo/node_modules/@expo/cli/build/src/start/server/metro/metroErrorInterface.js
    - /usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo/node_modules/@expo/cli/build/src/start/server/metro/bundleApiRoutes.js
    - /usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo/node_modules/@expo/cli/build/src/start/server/metro/MetroBundlerDevServer.js
    - /usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo/node_modules/@expo/cli/build/src/start/server/DevServerManager.js
    - /usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo/node_modules/@expo/cli/build/src/start/startAsync.js
    - /usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo/node_modules/@expo/cli/build/src/start/index.js
    - /usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo/node_modules/@expo/cli/build/bin/cli
    - /usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo/bin/cli
    Error: Cannot find module 'metro-cache'
    Require stack:
    - /usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo/node_modules/@expo/metro-config/build/ExpoMetroConfig.js
    - /usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo/node_modules/@expo/cli/build/src/start/server/serverLogLikeMetro.js
    - /usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo/node_modules/@expo/cli/build/src/start/server/getStaticRenderFunctions.js
    - /usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo/node_modules/@expo/cli/build/src/start/server/metro/metroErrorInterface.js
    - /usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo/node_modules/@expo/cli/build/src/start/server/metro/bundleApiRoutes.js
    - /usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo/node_modules/@expo/cli/build/src/start/server/metro/MetroBundlerDevServer.js
    - /usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo/node_modules/@expo/cli/build/src/start/server/DevServerManager.js
    - /usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo/node_modules/@expo/cli/build/src/start/startAsync.js
    - /usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo/node_modules/@expo/cli/build/src/start/index.js
    - /usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo/node_modules/@expo/cli/build/bin/cli
    - /usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo/bin/cli
        at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1143:15)
        at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:984:27)
        at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1231:19)
        at require (node:internal/modules/helpers:179:18)
        at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo/node_modules/@expo/metro-config/build/ExpoMetroConfig.js:36:23)
        at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1369:14)
        at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1427:10)
        at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1206:32)
        at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1022:12)
        at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1231:19)

Here's my package.json file:
{
  "name": "myapp",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start --dev-client",
    "android": "expo run:android",
    "ios": "expo run:ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "eject": "expo eject"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@expo/vector-icons": "^14.0.1",
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.11",
    "@react-native/metro-config": "^0.74.83",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^5.11.15",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^5.9.8",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^5.14.9",
    "apisauce": "^3.0.1",
    "expo": "^51.0.0",
    "expo-build-properties": "~0.12.1",
    "expo-dev-client": "~4.0.11",
    "expo-device": "~6.0.2",
    "expo-in-app-purchases": "~14.1.1",
    "expo-linear-gradient": "~13.0.2",
    "expo-location": "~17.0.1",
    "expo-notifications": "^0.28.1",
    "expo-secure-store": "~13.0.1",
    "expo-splash-screen": "^0.27.4",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.12.1",
    "expo-updates": "^0.25.9",
    "formik": "^2.2.9",
    "jwt-decode": "^3.1.2",
    "lottie-react-native": "6.7.0",
    "moment": "^2.29.3",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "^0.74.1",
    "react-native-expo-image-cache": "^4.1.0",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.16.1",
    "react-native-purchases": "^4.6.1",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~3.10.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.10.1",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.31.1",
    "react-native-web": "~0.19.10",
    "react-native-webview": "13.8.6",
    "yup": "^0.32.11"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0"
  },
  "private": true
}


I ended up downgrading the expo to version 50.0.17 and all other dependencies to versions that npx expo-doctor told me to. Everything works fine now.


Run and install below expo/metro-config
npm install @expo/metro-config --save-dev

create a new file called metro.config.js in the root folder

Add below code to that metro.config.js file




const { getDefaultConfig } = require('@expo/metro-config');

const defaultConfig = getDefaultConfig(__dirname);

module.exports = {
  transformer: {
    // Custom transformer options if any
  },
  resolver: {
    // Custom resolver options if any
  },
  ...defaultConfig,
};



save and run npm start
